# Query with a variable

Tags: sql, django

I would like to execute a query with a variable

I tried to do this but it doesn't work

```
def requeteDB(sql_request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql_request)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row

def queryWithVar():
    var = 'something with spaces'
    return('''
           Select col1
           From table1
           Where col2 = %s
           ''', [var])
```

```
queryWithVar()
```

> ('\n           Select col1\n           From table1\n           Where col2 = %s\n           ', ['something'])

```
requeteDB(queryWithVar())
```

> TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your function returns tuple, so you need to unpack it when provide it's result to `execute` method, just use `*` syntax:

```
def requeteDB(sql_request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(*queryWithVar())
        row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row
```

Comment: hello, thank for your help. I use *requeteDB* with queries without variable in them, so i have to create antoher function  *requeteDBWithVar* for exemple with the * ?

Comment: I suppose yes. Or alternatively you can modify your `queryWithoutVar()` so that it returns tuple as well. Something like this `return ('Select * from table',)`. Now it returns tuple with one element in it.